# SVC Classifier to Keras CNN with probabilities or confidence to distinguish untrained classes

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, svm

This question is pretty similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54414392/convert-sklearn-svm-svc-classifier-to-keras-implementation) and based on [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2588) post over GitHub, in the sense that I am trying to convert an SVM multiclass classification model (e.g., using sklearn) to a Keras model.

Specifically, I am looking for a way of retrieving probabilities (similar to SVC `probability=True`) or confidence value at the end so that I can define some sort of threshold and be able to distinguish between trained classes and non-trained ones. That is if I train my model with 3 or 4 classes, but then use a 5th that it wasn't trained with, it will still output some prediction, even if totally wrong. I want to avoid that in some way.

I got the following working reasonably well, but it relies on picking the maximum value at the end (`argmax`), which I would like to avoid:

```
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(30, input_shape=(30,), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
  # output classes
  model.add(Dense(3, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.1)))
  # the activation is linear by default, which works; softmax makes the accuracy be stuck 33% if targeting 3 classes, or 25% if targeting 4.
  #model.add(Activation('softmax')) 
  model.compile(loss='categorical_hinge', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Any ideas on how to tackle this untrained-class problem? Something like Plat scaling or Temperature scaling would work, if I can still save the model as onnx.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, got *softmax* to work by scaling the features (input) of the model. No need for stop gradient or anything. I was specifically using really big numbers, which despite training well, were preventing *softmax* (logistic regression) to work properly. The scaling of the features can be done, for instance, through the following code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_std = scaler.fit_transform(X)
```

By doing this the output of the SVM-like model using keras is outputting probabilities as originally intended.